# Sending files and directories using scp

Tags: scp

I want to send the following files from my computer to a remote computer using `scp`.

```
Directory1
  File1
  File2
  Directory2
    File3
    File4
    ...
```

How can I send `File1`, `File2`, etc. such that they are saved to the same directories on the remote computer as they are on my computer (e.g. `Directory1` and `Directory2` are created on the remote computer and `Directory2` contains `File3` and `File4`)?

Comment: Use `rsync`, it has an option for copying a hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the directory "foo" from the local host to a remote host's directory "bar"

```
scp -r foo your_username@remotehost.edu:/some/remote/directory/bar
```

The -r tells it to copy recursively.